# Why in i18n blocktrans (django) a object, dict or list don't work?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-templates

I am using django i18n for supporting i18n. I've found out that in django blocktrans an object, dict directly doesn't work.

For example if I've got a object with name obj and i try using it like

```
{% blocktrans %} My name is {{ obj.name }} {% endblocktrans %}
```

will not work, but if I use it like

```
{% blocktrans with name=obj.name %} My name is {{ name }} {% endblocktrans %}
```

will work.

I just wish to know why first example didn't work but second worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django's `blocktrans` are passed to ugettext, which mark them as translation strings in the u"My name is %(name)s" form, which at runtime are processed with the context as mapping, ie `u"My name is %(name)s" % context. This does not allow for Django template style attribute resolution.

Comment: what you told is correct but why it is not accepting object.name when it can process a object or dict object. what is the problem with accessing the attributes of object or key of dict.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh : The `"some string %(var)s" % dict(var="yadda")` style of formatting is builtin in Python, it's not a Django feature, and this formatting does _not_ support Django style attribute resolution, nor any other arbitrary lookup rule, period. Please understand that this is outside django's scope - it's how Python (and gettext) work.

Answer (score 1):

From the Django documentation "To translate a template expression -- say, accessing object attributes or using template filters -- you need to bind the expression to a local variable for use within the translation block"

Without delving into the template code I would guess that the translation operation is performed before the getattr/automatic calling stuff that django does when rendering a template.